# save List<Model class> to sqlite

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-sqlite

I'm working on the Firebase app and I want to save a list of more than 5000 retrieved PricesList items into SQLite.

Here is my **Firebase code**:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            pricesArrayList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot PricesListDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                PricesList pricesList = PricesListDataSnapshot.getValue(PricesList.class);
                pricesArrayList.add(pricesList);

                // I don't know what is the insertion code for SQLite

            }

            // here goes the code for retrieved data from SQLite after it was saved from Firebase

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

and here is the **DB.class** code

```
private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "MyDB1.db";
    public static final String id = "_id";
    public static final String ItemCode = "ItemCode";
    public static final String Product = "Product";

    DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + DB_NAME + '(' + id
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + ItemCode + " TEXT ,"
                + Product + " TEXT ," +')';
        db.execSQL(create_sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_NAME );
    }
}
```

What code should be used for storing listo of items in SQLite database?
I'll be thankful to anyone how has the answer.

Comment: I think you should take a look at the tutorial in the official documentation. You can find a solution to your problem in this link:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DBHelper you need a method that insert your data in db so..
first: Create the method

```
public void isInsertData(Price price) {
   try {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
      insertValues.put(ItemCode, price.getItemCode());
      insertValues.put(Product, price.getProduct());
      db.insert(DB_NAME, null, insertValues);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I see that your table name looks similar to your database name, i recommend you change that but its if you want.

Second: we need a instance of our helper and call the new method, the next line goes in your iteration.

```
DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this); //or ActivityName.this
for (DataSnapshot PricesListDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            PricesList pricesList = PricesListDataSnapshot.getValue(PricesList.class);
            pricesArrayList.add(pricesList);
            dbHelper.isInsertData(pricesList);
  }
```

That´s it! Now you save data in your database.

I recommend you read this link if you have any question after that
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Comment: thank you for your advice "changing the name of table name to doesn't be similar to database name" i edited it but when i tried the codes above i'v no result and i got this message
`V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service`

Comment: Well, you only save data. You don´t see anything in console. The next step is make a query to get data from your database.

Comment: here is the query
`public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getProducts() {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> prolist;
prolist = new ArrayList<>();
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "PricesTable";
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(item_Code, cursor.getString(1));
map.put(ItemDesc, cursor.getString(2));
prolist.add(map);
} 
while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
return prolist;
}`

Comment: and here is the adapter that preview sqlite saved items 
`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = FB2sqLite.getProducts();
                    if (myList.size() != 0) {
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(FireBase_Prices.this, myList, R.layout.model,
                                new String[]{item_Code, ItemDesc},
                                new int[]{R.id.ItemCodeView, R.id.descTxt});
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }`

Comment: I see one problem but maybe not the unique, in your getProducts() method you have a request to writableDatabase but in this step you need a Readable Database, try to change this line SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();  with next line SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase(); and please tell me if works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hardly recommend you to use an ORM of your preference before using pure SQLite, they are easier to understand, easy to configure and more scalable than using pure SQLite. This is the one that I have use the most "GreenDao: http://greenrobot.org/greendao/ ", but if you don't want or like this one you can use any other, there are many out there. 
An ORM maps your data objects into tables of SQLite and provides all the methods needed to manage your database.
Inserting data using GreenDao ca be as easy as the following example:

```
NewsArticle[] newsArticles = new NewsArticle[600];
NewsArticle testArticle;
    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
         testArticle = new NewsArticle();
         testArticle.setTitle("title-text" + i);
         testArticle.setBody("body-text" + i);
         testArticle.setShortDescription("short-text" + i);
         testArticle.setDate(now);
         newsArticles[i] = testArticle;
    }
newsArticleDao.insertInTx(newsArticles);
```

Comment: thank you for your help bro. and i'll be grateful if you have any tutorial which explain ORM

Comment: Sure, in this video they go over the basics of what is an ORM and the principles of GreenDao https://youtu.be/bItvU7fX4xw. But anyways you will need to feed the official documentation on their site, don't be lazy, read it. http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/introduction/  http://greenrobot.org/documentation/how-to-get-started/.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to say thanks to everyone who helped me and special thanks to @Daniel Carreto.
I applied the steps and it works well, but I added a logical method **(if)** where **(if Sqlite is Empty)** call the firebase data and save it into SQLite then stop the calling of valueEventListener **(if not)** get the query of **SQLite.class**.
it works well but when i finish the activity and open it again the process starts again
here is the code after update

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (FB2sqLite == null) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = FB2sqLite.getProducts();
        if (myList.size() != 0) {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(FireBase_Prices.this, myList, R.layout.model,
                    new String[]{item_Code, ItemDesc},
                    new int[]{R.id.ItemCodeView, R.id.descTxt});
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    } else {

        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                pricesArrayList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot PricesListDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    PricesList pricesList = PricesListDataSnapshot.getValue(PricesList.class);
                    pricesArrayList.add(pricesList);
                    FB2sqLite.insert(pricesList);
                    FB2sqLite.close();
                }

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = FB2sqLite.getProducts();
                if (myList.size() != 0) {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(FireBase_Prices.this, myList, R.layout.model,
                            new String[]{item_Code, ItemDesc},
                            new int[]{R.id.ItemCodeView, R.id.descTxt});
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

how can i use **removeEventListener** and where is the position of this method?