# How to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database to mySqlite?

Tags: android, firebase, sqlite, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Sample data layout]

The above image shows the database structure of my Firebase Database and That is how an expense is saved in my firebase real time database. How can I get that data from firebase and store it in SQlite database in my android app with the help of the datamodel given below?

```java
public class Expense {
    public String id;
    public String amount;
    public String description;

    public Expense() {}

    // [START post_to_map]
    @Exclude
    public Map < String, Object > toMap() {
        HashMap < String, Object > result = new HashMap < > ();
        result.put("id", id);
        result.put("amount", amount);
        result.put("description", description);
        return result;
    }
    // [END post_to_map]


    public Expense(String id, String amount, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

The is the function that i use to add data to the SQLITE database

```java
 public boolean addExpense(Expense expense) {
     ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
     contentValues.put("expense_id", expense.getId());
     contentValues.put("expense_amount", expense.getAmount());
     contentValues.put("expense_description", expense.getDescription());
     SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
     db.insert(DBHelper.expenses_table, null, contentValues);
     return true;
 }
```

How can i Save the data from Realtime Database to the SQLite database?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Where are you getting data from Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at this answer.It's Related
[save List to sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304375/save-listmodel-class-to-sqlite)

**OR**

To save the data from firebase realtime database to sql database you should add a ValueEventListener to the DatabaseReference where you have stored the Expenses data and loop through each expense data and transfer it to addExpense() function.

Checkout this Sample

*Your Expense Datamodel:*

```java
public class Expense {
    public String id;
    public String amount;
    public String description;

    public Expense() {
    }

    // [START post_to_map]
    @Exclude
        public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("id", id);
        result.put("amount", amount);
        result.put("description", description);
        return result;
    }
    // [END post_to_map]


    public Expense(String id, String amount, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Here you are trying to collect a list of expenses from the firebase then you might need to use this method:

```java
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("path_to_your_expenses_reference");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot expensedata: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Expense expense = expensedata.getValue(Expense.class);
            addExpense(expense);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```